# Can I intercept the RavenDB HTTP API Post with custom code

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ravendb

When I would do a REST call form my javascript client to the server via     domain.com\api\docs\bobs_address

Is it possible to intercept the http post at the server endpoint that means inside my web api controller or does the call of the above url go directly into my Raven database?

Assuming there is a document with an id of "bobs_address", RavenDB will respond with the contents of that document and an HTTP 200 OK response code:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 

{  
    "FirstName": "Bob",  
    "LastName": "Smith",  
    "Address": "5 Elm St." 
}
```

If the URL specified does not point to a valid document, RavenDB follows HTTP conventions and responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

In RavenDB 3.0, we are using OWIN as our middleware, and you can intercept the requests before/after they arrive to RavenDB.
However, what do you want to do with them once you intercepted them?

Comment: Sorry Ayende for the late reply! In my DocumentController there could be a Create method. The request has an attachment + title as action parameter. In the action I  go to the azure file storage and put the attachment there. The azure location should return me some unique id/string/path. This identifier + title is written now into the ravendb 'table'. I need to save very much data with my SPA in a database but database is not the correct place to save 10TB within 5 years... You understand my idea?

Comment: I know owin + topshelf for running the host in a windows service. But why do you use owin for ravendb? Asking not knowing ravendb...

Comment: Would you please be that kind and tell me HOW to intercept the requests?